# Join two tables on different columns

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables like below in mysql

city

```
id   from     to

1     101     102
```

travel

```
id name

101  ABC

102  XYZ
```

I am trying to join table such that I will get ABC as source and XYZ as destination. I tried multiple combinations but not getting expected result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join the `travel` table twice with different alias names

```
select c.id, 
       t1.name as city_from, 
       t2.name as city_to
from city c
join travel t1 on t1.id = c.`from`
join travel t2 on t2.id = c.`to`
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain how it works. I was trying with single join on two columns but was not getting one row result

Comment: Since you need different results for each column, you need to join the same table twice. First against the `from` column to get the cities for those IDs and then join again against the other column.